# Grails 3 Camel Routing

Tags: grails, apache-camel, grails3

I am wondering is there a way to automatically add RouteBuilder classes to the camel context in grails 3? I was using the https://grails.org/plugin/routing but it no longer works for grails 3.

Comment: There is an unpublished grails3 version - looks unmaintained, but may be a start for you - https://github.com/padcom/grails-routing

Comment: @erichelgeson Yes I had a look at it but wasn't able to replicate the functionality. Some how its getting the route classes from the application?

def routeClasses = application.routeClasses